# How to display all posts from post_type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to display all posts from a different post_type (books, movies, music) in index.php

Like this:

```
BOOKS    
  Book 1 
  Book 2 
  Book 3 
  ...

MOVIES
  Movie 1
  Movie 2
  Movie 3
  ...

MUSIC
  Music 1
  Music 2
  Music 3
  ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to edit the index.php template page and run multiple wp_queries for each of the post types.

```
// Setup arguments.
$args = array(
// Get the "movies" post type.
'post_type' => 'movies',
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
// Instantiate new query instance.
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($my_query->have_posts()):
while($my_query->have_posts()):
$my_query->the_post();
// Do your stuff here
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
// Setup arguments.
$args = array(
// "music" post type.
'post_type' => 'music',
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
// Instantiate new query instance.
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($my_query->have_posts()):
while($my_query->have_posts()):
$my_query->the_post();
// Do your stuff here
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wanted to do something similar, I came across this [answer by Tomás Cot](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160821/121736)

**The bottom line:**

You need to specify which post types to display where it says `post_type1`, `post_type2`, and `post_type3` on `line #3` and you can add more if you need.

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'article', 'post_type1', 'post_type2', 'post_type3') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

**The result?**

All the post types you add will be added to the `index.php` post query. 
They will be displayed just like standard WordPress posts in your archive

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! One problem remains: how to order the posts by post types and not by date?